# Unable the perform import using CSV file, permission issue on CRM dynamics

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have created a Data Map- 'Ipad App Geveva Event' for importing lead records using csv file from Import function on CRM.
I have then set the permission on role which user is having. But when I click on Import option in the final it's getting failed saying that "You do not enough privileges to access the Microsoft CRM Dynamics objects.

1. Modified the role to give access for importing csv file

[image]

Importing the csv file from Systems-> Data Management-> Imports

[image]

Clicking on the next button to proceed further

[image]

Again clicking on the next button to proceed further

[image]

Finally now when I click on import button it's getting failed. Don't know what permission I have been missing on the role. please assist for the below error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the more specific error message. You should be able to find something that looks similar to 'prvCreateContact' which usually describes the exact permission that user is missing.

- [How to enable tracing in Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907490).
- [How to turn on developer errors in Microsoft CRM 2011 (aka Titan or 5.0).](http://rostacik.net/2011/07/07/how-to-turn-on-developer-errors-in-microsoft-crm-2011-aka-titan-or-5-0/).

Then compare that missing privilege with the tables on the MSDN, that should help you to work out which privilege you need to add the user.

[Security Role UI to Privilege Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh547441.aspx) (this is the 2011 version but it should be pretty similar).

Answer (score 0):

I was only missing 'Append to' privilege from the role in the first image- fixed and now working for all users who has this role assigned with him. This nightmare has gone now.